# What's eHTML5 in Dell iDRAC's virtual consoel plugin types?

Tags: dell, drac, html5

Dell's PowerEdge R6525 iDRAC9 has the following virtual console types:

- ActiveX
- Java
- HTML5
- eHTML5

I Googled and all eHTML5 results relate to Dell but found no definition of eHTML5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It stands simply for *"enhanced"* HTML5.

And it is Dell jargon to distinguish between their regular HTML5 virtual console and the enhanced HTML5 option.

Depending on the web browser that you're using it may offer slightly different features than the regular HTML5 console.

Comment: i thought eHTML5 is some new technology since it's listed after ActiveX, Java and HTML5. :)